# Slow performance with CGlayer Drawing

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgpath, cglayer

I am using **CGlayers** for drawing, as the documentation says, it's more efficient way to render drawing on canvas.

I basically draw into CGlayers and the draw the layer into the graphics context using **CGContextDrawLayerInRect**

Here is my drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{      
   switch (m_drawStep)
   {
       case DRAW:
       {               
           CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();//Get a reference to current context(The context to draw)

           if(self.currentDrawingLayer == nil)//Potential leak of memory- static analyzer
           {
               CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
               CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width * scale, self.bounds.size.height * scale);
               CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
               CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
               CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
               self.currentDrawingLayer = layer;
           }           

           CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(self.currentDrawingLayer);//Potential leak of memory- static analyzer
           CGContextBeginPath(layerContext);
           CGContextAddPath(layerContext, mutablePath);
           CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext, self.lineWidth);
           CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext, self.lineColor.CGColor);
           CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(layerContext, self.lineColor.CGColor);
           CGContextSetBlendMode(layerContext,kCGBlendModeNormal);
           CGContextStrokePath(layerContext);
           CGPathRelease(mutablePath);

           CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.currentDrawingLayer );//Potential leak of memory- static analyzer
       }
           break;

       case UNDO:
       {                          
           CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();           

           if(self.currentDrawingLayer == nil)//Potential leak of memory- static analyzer
           {
               CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
               CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width * scale, self.bounds.size.height * scale);
               CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
               CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
               CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
               self.currentDrawingLayer = layer;
           }                                

           CGContextRef layerContext1 = CGLayerGetContext(self.currentDrawingLayer );//Potential leak of memory- static analyzer
           CGContextClearRect(layerContext1, self.bounds);

          for(NSArray *undoArray in m_parentUndoArray)
          {
               for(int i =0; i<[undoArray count];i++)
              {
                   DrawingPath *drawPath = [undoArray objectAtIndex:i];
                   CGPathRef path = drawPath.path.CGPath;
                   mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(path);


                   CGContextBeginPath(layerContext1);
                   CGContextAddPath(layerContext1, mutablePath);
                   CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext1, drawPath.pathWidth.floatValue);
                   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext1, drawPath.pathColor.CGColor);

                   if([drawPath.pathColor isEqual:[UIColor clearColor]])
                   {
                        CGContextSetBlendMode(layerContext1,kCGBlendModeClear);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        CGContextSetBlendMode(layerContext1,kCGBlendModeNormal);
                   }

                       CGContextStrokePath(layerContext1);
                       CGPathRelease(mutablePath);
                   }
               }

                 CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.currentDrawingLayer);//Potential leak of memory- static analyzer
           }
        }
           break;



    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

In my touches Moved function function, I create the UIBezeirPath and convert it to CGPath.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{          
   self.currentPath = [[DrawingPath alloc] init];

   if(m_eraseButtonClicked)
   {
      [self.currentPath setPathColor:[UIColor clearColor]];         
   }
   else
   {
        [self.currentPath setPathColor:self.lineColor];            
   }

   CGPathRef cgPath = self.currentPath.path.CGPath;
    mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(cgPath);

        [m_undoArray addObject:self.currentPath];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

  }
```

In touches ended

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [m_parentUndoArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:m_undoArray]];

}
```

The problems which , I am facing are below

1) I tested with Time profiler, **CGContextDrawLayerInRect**, takes 90% of the time while drawing, So I want to know how we can the reduce this time taken by this method and optimize the drawRect method.

2)If I draw few lengthy lines and start doing continously undo/redo then also you can see  **CGContextDrawLayerInRect** which takes lot of time.

3) If I erase some drawn lines and start doing undo/redo repeatedly, even worse happens,my app crashes with memory warning, I dont know whats going wrong with erase, that its taking so much memory.

Edit :Code, updated to show where the static analyser says their is a memory issue

Comment: Is Instruments reporting any memory leaks with the Leaks instrument? Do you have zombies enabled (which would result in deallocated memory never actually being deallocated)? Did you run the static analyzer in Xcode on your code to see if it reports any issues with your memory management?

Comment: Hello @Gavin, It reports memory leaks with CoreGraphics functions, I dont know about zombies and I have not run any static analyzer

Comment: I ran static analyzer, its reported issues at lines of code above, which I have updated.

Comment: Hello @Gavin, what you have to say, about this

Answer (score 1):

From my own experiments, it seems that iOS will sometimes use the GPU and sometimes the CPU for CGContextDrawLayerInRect, depending on the size of the layer being copied (and potentially other factors). When it uses the CPU, it is 20x slower.

The only solution is to reduce the size of the updated area, by using setNeedsDisplayInRect instead of setNeedsDisplay, and also adding CGContextClipToRect(context, rect) in your drawRect code.